# Setting $rootScope & changing its value

Tags: angularjs, rootscope

I want so set a `$rootScope` variable `stateSelection` value default as `false`.

So when my applciation runs the value of the `$rootScope.stateSelection` will be `false`. I want to know how to set it at the time of initialization of app.

Right now i am setting it in my `Auth` Service in `login` function.

When User logs in & selects a state i call a method in a controller named `clickSelection()` & in this function i change the `$rootScope.stateSelection = true;`.

I get a problem when i refresh the page, the value of `$rootScope.stateSelection` becomes `false`.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using cookies ?

Comment: not yet...i was just looking for cookies only....if you find some simple tutorial...pls share it with me.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookieStore . I guess this may help you.

Answer (score 1):

$rootScope.stateSelection will always be false on refresh unless you're persisting the value somewhere.

If you are persisting the data somewhere, you can use the resolve property (read more about resolves [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve) ) to return a function that will set the value before loading the page:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl : 'views/home.html',
    controller : 'HomeController',
    resolve : {
      authenticate : function auth(authService){
         // Function to get the stateSelection value
         return authService.getStateSelection()
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Is there any other way around. if i can set some value globally & change it in a controller.

Comment: @Anup Even if you set something globally, if there isn't any persistence, the variables will reset on page refresh. An option, if you don't want to interact with a server, is to use localstorage for persistence, you can read more about that here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#localStorage